# Dompdf is not rendering image

Tags: php, html, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF library to convert HTML to PDF at runtime. However, I am facing an issue related to images. System displays images when I render HTML code but when I convert it into PDF, it replace all images by "broken_image.png". I have placed complete url (given below) of images, its still not working for me :/ . Below is the example image url:

```
<img src='http://img.uksoccershop.com/images/man-utd-gk-away-shirt-2012-13.jpg'/>
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using 0.6.1? If so and dompdf is accessible via your web server browse to dompdf/www/setup.php and look for any red flags.

Comment: Based on what you've posted so far I'm guessing that maybe allow_url_fopen is set to false. Do you get any PHP errors (say in your log file)?

Answer (score 0):

To enable remote images for DOMPDF u have to alter the config `dompdf_config.inc.php`
Look near line 284 :

```
def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", false);
```

This should be set to `true`. Also be sure that the temp directory defined near line 103 is writeable :

```
def("DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR", sys_get_temp_dir());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already set DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE to true but I didn't get any temp directory path in the method define for it: function sys_get_temp_dir() {
    if (!empty($_ENV['TMP'])) { return realpath($_ENV['TMP']); }
    if (!empty($_ENV['TMPDIR'])) { return realpath( $_ENV['TMPDIR']); }
    if (!empty($_ENV['TEMP'])) { return realpath( $_ENV['TEMP']); }
    $tempfile=tempnam(uniqid(rand(),TRUE),'');
    if (file_exists($tempfile)) {
    unlink($tempfile);
    return realpath(dirname($tempfile));
    }
  } here, there is no defined temp directory. Please tell me temp directory path?

Comment: How bout the temp folder?

Comment: are you talking about temp folder of server or of the project? In both case, I have set permissions to writable but its still not working

Comment: the temp folder defined in `DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR`. In my project its seems i've adjustted this value to `getcwd().'/tmp'` because it woudln't work with `sys_get_temp_dir()`

Comment: Yes sys_get_temp_dir() is not working for me even. So I also change DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR to  getcwd().'/tmp and for this, I created a "tmp" directory with write permissions into dompdf directory. but its still not working

Answer (score -3):

DOMPDF is not a browser, it won't download images or any other assets, it simply converts HTML/CSS into a PDF representation.

You'll need something like [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry if I conveyed improper messgae but I just want to convert HTML to PDF and DOMPDF is working fine on this except in case of images. It is not displaying images that present in HTML page

Comment: dompdf is capable of rendering images just fine. Check out the image examples here: http://pxd.me/dompdf/www/examples.php